# How do I pass data between recyclerview and many fragments

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi I have a simple app that features a recyclerView with list items (each representing a "employee" object
 i use this tuto https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ using tabhost but when i click in item recycler view i want to pass some data in one of tabs 
    recycler view item ===> to fragment

```
this is xml fragment 

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.iset.tse.Employee.OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Information de contact :"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/statusBarColor"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.312"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_emp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="username"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.204"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



code Java



public class OneFragment extends Fragment


{


    TextView txt_name;

    public OneFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        txt_name=(TextView) txt_name.findViewById(R.id.name_emp);
        String name = getArguments().getString("name");
        txt_name.setText(name);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }
    public static OneFragment newInstance(String nameValue) {
        String name;

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
        name = nameValue;
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

Activity xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.iset.tse.Employee.Details_Employee">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="421dp"
        android:layout_height="211dp"
        android:background="#1ABC9C"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/employee"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.53" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_emp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:background="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_dark"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="541dp"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

java activity code


        //tabs
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

     /*   Date_sys = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_sys);
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        Date_sys.setText(currentDateTimeString);
        chechk_in.setText(chechkin);
    */
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("ONE");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_info, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("TWO");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_time, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);


    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    String name;

    public void sendData(String nameAdapter) {
        name = nameAdapter;
        if (name != null) {
            OneFragment med_frag = OneFragment.newInstance(name);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.viewpager, med_frag)
                    .commit();
        }
    }


this is My adapter

public class EmployeeAdapter extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeAdapter.EmployeeHolder> {
    final List<Employee> EmployeeList;
    private Context context;

    @Override

    public EmployeeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.employee_row,parent,false);

        EmployeeHolder holder= new EmployeeHolder(row);
        return holder;
    }

   public EmployeeAdapter(List<Employee> EmployeeList) {
    this.EmployeeList=EmployeeList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeHolder holder, int position) {
        Employee employee=EmployeeList.get(position);
       // holder.id.setText(employee.getId());
        holder.name.setText(employee.getName());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return EmployeeList.size();

    }



     public class EmployeeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private final Context context;

        TextView name;

        public EmployeeHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_emp);



            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ((Details_Employee)context).sendData(name.getText().toString());

}
```

Comment: see [Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing)

Comment: Try to make your model class(Pojo Class) Singleton. And then set you data as needed. Making your class singleton will save the value of data until its not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

So what you require is a model class for your data and sharing of data from one fragment to another.
You can share data using ArrayList(of your model class) as the argument for 2nd fragment from the first one and getting that ArrayList in your constructor.

eg: frag A and frag B and a model class named model.

Firstly a model class to store all your data eg

**model class**

```
public class model{

private String item1,item2,item3;
private int a,b,c;

public model(String item1, String item2, String item3, int a, int b, int c) {
    this.item1 = item1;
    this.item2 = item2;
    this.item3 = item3;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

public String getItem1() {
    return item1;
}

public void setItem1(String item1) {
    this.item1 = item1;
}

public String getItem2() {
    return item2;
}

public void setItem2(String item2) {
    this.item2 = item2;
}

public String getItem3() {
    return item3;
}

public void setItem3(String item3) {
    this.item3 = item3;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public int getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(int c) {
    this.c = c;
}
}
```

Now in
**frag A**

```
public class frag_A extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
MainAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<model> data_list;//DEFINE AN ARRAYLIST OF YOUR MODEL CLASS


public frag_A() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_A, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_service);
    data_list = new ArrayList<>();

    //THIS IS WHERE MODEL CLASS IS USED TO SET DATA IN ARRAYLIST

    model new_data=new model(item1,item2,item3,a,b,c);

    data_list.add(model);//add the model data to your arraylist

    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(data_list);//SET ARRAYLIST IN ADAPTER

    //set all recyclerview components you want
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //onclicklistener for recyclerview items
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new mehakmeet.startup.com.v1.home.room_services.food_order.Adapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new mehakmeet.startup.com.v1.home.room_services.food_order.Adapter.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                    //THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE DATA IS SHARED
                    service_details hk = new service_details(data_list);

                    //YOU CAN SHARE THE POSITION CLICKED HERE using bundle
                     Bundle args=new Bundle();
                  args.putString("position",String.valueOf(position);
                    hk.setArguments(args);

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.main_home, hk).addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();


                }
            })
    );


    return v;
}
}
```

Now to get that arraylist parameter , implement this arraylist in your frag_B constructor

**frag_B**

```
public class frag_B extends Fragment {

ArrayList<model> data_list;//Again define an arraylist of your model class
TextView item1,item2,item3
int a,b,c;

Button make_book;

//This is the constructor that uses the arraylist from previous fragment and can be used as arraylist in this fragment.
public frag_B(ArrayList<model> data_list) {
    this.data_list=data_list;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_service_details, container, false);
    item1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_1);
    item2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_2);
    item3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_3);
    //HERE GET THE POSITION CLICKED HERE
    int position=Integer.parseInt(getArguments().getString("position");

    item1.setText(data_list.get(position).getitem1());
    item2.setText(data_list.get(position).getitem2());
    item3.setText(data_list.get(position).getitem3());

    a=data_list.get(position).getA();
    b=data_list.get(position).getB();
    c=data_list.get(position).getC();


    return v;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for that. Checkout the readme for how to use it.